# MOQ: Setting up a method which fills a collection inside the object passed as parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a class named "CollectionPager" which has a collection inside that of type List. I have a method "RetrieveList" which takes a "CollectionPager" as input and populates "List" in side that. This method doesn't return any value.

I need to mock a function which calls "RetrieveList". However, since it doesn't return any value, whatever input was fed into Mock is not taken into consideration and this collection(List) always has a count of 0.

Any possible ways to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post some code? How is your current test looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need the `Callback` (see also [Moq quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)) method to setup some logic when mocking a void function.

Here is sample test which demonstrates the usage:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IRetrieveListService>();
mock.Setup(m => m.RetrieveList(It.IsAny<CollectionPager>()))
    .Callback<CollectionPager>(p =>
                                    {
                                        p.List.Add("testItem1");
                                        p.List.Add("testItem2");
                                    });
var sut = new OtherService(mock.Object);
sut.SomeMethodToTest();
```

Assuming your classes looks like something like these:

```cs
public class CollectionPager
{
    public CollectionPager()
    {
        List = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> List { get; private set; }
}

public interface IRetrieveListService
{
    void RetrieveList(CollectionPager pager);
}

public class RetrieveListService : IRetrieveListService
{
    public void RetrieveList(CollectionPager pager)
    {
        pager.List.Add("item1");
        pager.List.Add("item2");
    }
}

public class OtherService
{
    private readonly IRetrieveListService retrieveListService;

    public OtherService(IRetrieveListService retrieveListService)
    {
        this.retrieveListService = retrieveListService;
    }

    public void SomeMethodToTest()
    {
        var collectionPager = new CollectionPager();
        retrieveListService.RetrieveList(collectionPager);
        // in your test collectionPager.Item contains: testItem1, testItem2
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. Forgot to mention CollectionPager is a generic class. And I now get an error "Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (ICollectionPager`1) cannot invoke callback with parameters (CollectionPager`1)." The line in my test looks like this: mockrepo.Setup(x => x.GetService<Entity>().RetrieveList(It.IsAny<CollectionPager<Entity>>())).Callback<CollectionPager<Entity>>(elemap => elemap.Collection.AddRange(entityCollection.Collection));

Comment: Awesome. Got it now. Just needed to change CollectionPager to ICollectionPager. Thanks a ton man.